# Phonegap 3.5 android 4.4 camera photo album very slow to retrieved

Tags: cordova, photo, android-4.4-kitkat, photo-gallery

I upgrade my phonegap project to latest version 3.5 . However I found tat it is very slow to retrieve the image when I take any photo. Sometime the image appear. Sometime is not appear. Btw I also not able to selected any image from album. Any one face this issue before?

Please c my code

```
 $("#cameraBtn").bind("click", function () {
                $("#popupGallery").popup("close");
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccessRE, onFail, {
                    quality: 30,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                });

                event.preventDefault() ;
            });



  $("#galleryBtn").bind("click", function () {
                    $("#popupGallery").popup("close");

                    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccessRE, onFail, {
                        quality: 30,
                        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
                    });

                    event.preventDefault() ;
                });
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: it actually is image size issue. You need to resize it first

Comment: thanks for the tip. we are actully writing these days our own custom camera. so it turns out that asking for camera preview prevent some u.i so its better to do it in some other thread